# How to use render a 2D overlay with DirectX 9

Tags: c++, direct3d, directx-9

So I have a game I'm working on in C++ with DirectX 9. It's 3D, but I want to have a 2D overlay. I've heard that I could use D3DXMatrixOrthoLH, but I'm very confused on how to use it. I'm more familiar with OpenGL, where I could simply switch between 3D and 2D by initiating the view. An example of how to do this with DirectX 9 would be great!

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ID3DXSprite` class in the D3DX9 library to draw 2D textures for a HUD.

You can use identity transforms and draw using normalized coordinates (-1,-1 to 1,1) with depth testing off, but most people find it less intuitive to position elements. Instead, they create a simple orthographic projection transform that maps the normalized coordinates to something more natural like pixels (0,0 to width,height). You can use `D3DXMatrixOrthoOffCenterLH` if you are using left-handed view coordinates or `D3DXMatrixOrthoOffCenterRH` if you are using right-handed view coordinates (which doesn't matter for 2D drawing but it is less confusing to make it consistent with your 3D drawing).

> Why are you using legacy DirectX 9 which is over a decade old? If you were using Direct3D 11 instead, you can make use of [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) and the `SpriteBatch` class to draw your HUD. The DirectX SDK is deprecated, the D3DX library is deprecated, D3DXMath is deprecated, and debugging for DirectX 9 is not supported on Windows 8 or later. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx)

Comment: I can't use Direct3D 11 because I'm using MinGW with CLion and I can't seem to get it to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help guys. I've decided to scratch DirectX and go back to good old OpenGL, which I'm much more familiar with.